# Why is there no hybrid class-protocol type in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm relatively new to Swift, and one thing that has frustrated me is the inability to create a single type that represents both a class and protocol (similar to `Class<Protocol> *` in Objective-C).  There is the `protocol<Protocol1, Protocol2>` operator which can create a new protocol type from multiple protocols; so my question is, why is this not possible with a class and a protocol?

I am aware that this can be accomplished using generics (e.g. `<T: Class where T: Protocol>`).  However, this seems kludgy, especially in situations where you might want to store that type in an instance variable but don't want to add generics to your class for what would would be considered an implementation detail.

I would like to better understand why this is not possible in Swift.  Specifically, I am interested in how class and protocol types are implemented (or defined) and why it is not possible to combine them into a single type as a result.

Comment: I don't think my question is a duplicate because I am asking _why_ (from a language design perspective) it is not possible to combine class and protocol types rather than looking for a workaround.

Comment: Ok I removed the "possible duplicate" tag!

Comment: This just gets you a different closure reason. "Why *did* Apple do ___?" questions can't be answered authoritatively by anyone but Apple (i.e. not by the SO community, and "Why *would* Apple do ___?" questions are opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

Let's declare a protocol and a class

```
protocol Wearable { }
class Computer { }
```

Then let's declare 3 classes

```
class AppleWatch: Computer, Wearable { }
class Mac: Computer { }
class Jeans: Wearable { }
```

And now a method that accepts a value that must extend `Computer` and conform to `Wearable`

```
func foo<T:Computer where T: Wearable>(something:T) { }
```

And finally let's test them:

```
foo(AppleWatch()) // OK
foo(Mac()) // error at compile time
foo(Jeans()) // error at compile time
```

Is it what you mean?